# Angular 2 element dynamic ref

Tags: angular, popover

I'm using this package to create a popover in my app: 
https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-popover 
The problem is I have a table with `ngFor` for data, so I need different popovers for different rows. Here is the code:

```
<div class="dt-row" *ngFor="let key of keys">
  <popover-content #actions
                   title="Actions"
                   placement="bottom"
                   [animation]="false"
                   [closeOnClickOutside]="true"
                   [closeOnMouseOutside]="false"
                   [disabled]="false"
                   [onHover]="false">
    <a>Edit</a>
    <a>Delete</a>
  </popover-content>

  <div [popover]="actions">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

So `actions` ref is same for all `ngFor` instances. 
How can I make that ref dynamic? Something like `[ref]="'actions-' + key.id"`.

Comment: You could use index. `*ngFor="let key of keys; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn"` and then `[ref]="'actions-' + index"`

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but it looks like angular doesn't know such directive as `[ref]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the comment suggests you would use the index:

```
<div class="dt-row" *ngFor="let key of keys; let i = index;">
            <popover-content #i
                             title="Actions"
                             placement="bottom"
                             [animation]="false"
                             [closeOnClickOutside]="true"
                             [closeOnMouseOutside]="false" >
              {{key.interestingInfo}}
                <a>Edit - {{key.name}}</a>
                <a>Delete - {{key.name}}</a>
            </popover-content>

            <div [popover]="i">
                {{key.clickText + key.name}}
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's a link to a working plunker demonstrating the popup-content has different content:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kVJSnn?p=preview

Comment: Wow, that's really working O_o I don't understand how, but thanks!

Comment: it works because reference #i is not really used, if you remove it, it will work the same. If you dont't implement in ts file a @ViewChild property to have access to the DOM element in typescript or use that reference in other parts of the html template, for example passing it as parameter of a method, it has no sense to declare a reference # for nothing